# Change data types from Advanced Editor vs Data Conversion Transformation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-data-types

I am using SSIS to create some packages. I have gotten confused around the *Data Conversion Transformation* component and changing columns data types from Advanced editor

If I can go into the advanced editor and change the data type of my output, why would I need to input the Data Conversion Transformation?

Is this just down to preference or is there a difference between using both approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Before showing the difference between both approaches, i will try to give an overview of the data conversion types.*

### Implicit vs Explicit conversion

There are 2 different type of data type conversion:

- Implicit conversion: Implicit conversions are not visible to the user. SQL Server automatically converts the data from one data type to another. For example, when a smallint is compared to an int, the smallint is implicitly converted to int before the comparison proceeds.
- Explicit conversion: Explicit conversions use the CAST or CONVERT functions or other tools.

From the following Microsoft Grid you can see what data types can be converted with each approach:

[image]

If you need to know what are the SSIS data types relevant to the data types of SQL Server database engine *(mentioned in the Grid above)*, then you can refer to the following documentation:

- [Integration Services Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017)

---

### Advanced Editor vs Data Conversion Transformation

- When changing data types from the **Advanced editor** you are performing **implicit data types conversion** since the Source/Destination Component try to convert automatically the data type of the column.
- Using **Data Conversion Transformation** you are performing **explicit conversion**. Since it is mentioned on the article above that:

> Use the Data Conversion transformation to **cast the data type** of a column from one data type to a different data type

More details can be found at:

- [SSIS Data types: Change from the Advanced Editor vs Data Conversion Transformations](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-data-types-change-from-the-advanced-editor-vs-data-conversion-transformations/)

---

### References

- [Data type conversion (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-and-explicit-conversion)
- [Data Conversion Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/data-conversion-transformation?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Working with SSIS Data Types](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/working-with-ssis-data-types/)